# Django filter column with OR statement

Tags: python, django

I found a question very similar to this one but that one did not specify how to return a specific column and I have been trying combinations for the past few hours with no luck.

```
home_team_list2 = PreviousLossesNbav1WithDateAgg.objects.values_list('actual_over_under_result_field', flat=True).filter(Q(away_team_field="Chicago") | Q(home_team_field="Chicago"))
```

This does not throw me any errors but it does not return anything. I am attempting to return that specific column from my models filtering on away team or home team equal to "Chicago"

Here is the model I am attempting to pull from:

```
class PreviousLossesNbav1WithDateAgg(models.Model):
    home_team_field = models.TextField(db_column='HOME TEAM:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_team_field = models.TextField(db_column='AWAY TEAM:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    projected_points_field = models.FloatField(db_column='PROJECTED POINTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_injury = models.TextField(db_column='Home Injury', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    away_injury = models.TextField(db_column='Away Injury', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    game_points_with_formula_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='GAME POINTS WITH FORMULA:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    game_money_line_field = models.FloatField(db_column='GAME MONEY LINE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    over_or_under = models.TextField(db_column='OVER OR UNDER', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    actual_game_points_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='ACTUAL GAME POINTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_team_points_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='AWAY TEAM POINTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_team_points_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='HOME TEAM POINTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    actual_over_under_result_field = models.TextField(db_column='ACTUAL OVER UNDER RESULT:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    percentage_won_field = models.FloatField(db_column='Percentage Won:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    win_or_lose_field = models.TextField(db_column='Win Or Lose:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_assists_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='AWAY ASSISTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_blocks_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='AWAY BLOCKS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_defensive_rebounds_per_game_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='AWAY DEFENSiVE REBOUNDS PER GAME:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_effective_field_goal_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY EFFECTIVE FIELD GOAL %:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_fg_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY FG %:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_fg_attempts_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='AWAY FG ATTEMPTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_fico_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY FICO:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_free_throw_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY FREE THROW %:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_free_throw_rate_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY FREE THROW RATE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_offensive_rebounds_per_game_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='AWAY OFFENSIVE REBOUNDS PER GAME:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_personal_fouls_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='AWAY PERSONAL FOULS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_points_per_game_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY POINTS PER GAME:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_steal_percentage_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY STEAL PERCENTAGE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_team_3_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY TEAM 3%:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_team_opp_ppg_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY TEAM OPP PPG:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_team_pace_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY TEAM PACE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_team_projected_points_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY TEAM PROJECTED POINTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_total_shot_percentage_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY TOTAL SHOT PERCENTAGE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_turnover_per_game_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='AWAY TURNOVER PER GAME:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    away_turnover_percentage_field = models.FloatField(db_column='AWAY TURNOVER PERCENTAGE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_assists_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='HOME ASSISTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_blocks_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='HOME BLOCKS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_defensive_rebounds_per_game_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='HOME DEFENSiVE REBOUNDS PER GAME:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_effective_field_goal_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME EFFECTIVE FIELD GOAL %:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_fg_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME FG %:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_fg_attempts_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='HOME FG ATTEMPTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_fico_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME FICO:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_free_throw_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME FREE THROW %:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_free_throw_rate_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME FREE THROW RATE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_offensive_rebounds_per_game_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='HOME OFFENSIVE REBOUNDS PER GAME:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_personal_fouls_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='HOME PERSONAL FOULS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_points_per_game_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME POINTS PER GAME:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_steal_percentage_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME STEAL PERCENTAGE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_team_3_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME TEAM 3%:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_team_opp_ppg_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME TEAM OPP PPG:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_team_pace_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME TEAM PACE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_team_projected_points_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME TEAM PROJECTED POINTS:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_total_shot_percentage_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME TOTAL SHOT PERCENTAGE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_turnover_per_game_field = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='HOME TURNOVER PER GAME:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    home_turnover_percentage_field = models.FloatField(db_column='HOME TURNOVER PERCENTAGE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    date_field = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DATE:', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'previous_losses_nbav1_with_date_agg'
```

Comment: Look at the SQL that Django is generating.  That will give you a clue: https://avilpage.com/2018/05/django-tips-tricks-log-sql-queries-to-console.html

Comment: @RossRogers Thanks, I will have to get this installed, looks awesome!

Comment: @RossRogers any clue if it works with Django 2.0.7? When I went to install it started uninstalling that version and currently my page needs that version specifically to run.

Comment: Was able to find a way to print out the query to quickly read it, this seems like a fun one

```SELECT `previous_losses_nbav1_with_date_agg`.`ACTUAL OVER UNDER RESULT:` FROM `previous_losses_nbav1_with_date_agg` WHERE (`previous_losses_nbav1_with_date_agg`.`AWAY TEAM:` = Chicago OR `previous_losses_nbav1_with_date_agg`.`HOME TEAM:` = Chicago)```

Seems to randomly insert my table name over and over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put `filter` first and then `values_list`.
This should work.

```
home_team_list2 = PreviousLossesNbav1WithDateAgg.objects.filter(
Q(away_team_field="Chicago") | Q(home_team_field="Chicago")
).values_list('actual_over_under_result_field', flat=True)
```

I tried this on my local machine and it worked fine.

```
SELECT `previous_losses_nbav1_with_date_agg`.`ACTUAL OVER UNDER RESULT:` 
FROM `previous_losses_nbav1_with_date_agg` WHERE 
(`previous_losses_nbav1_with_date_agg`.`AWAY TEAM:` = Chicago OR 
`previous_losses_nbav1_with_date_agg`.`HOME TEAM:` = Chicago)
```

This generated output of  `query` is not valid SQL because "Django never actually interpolates the parameters: it sends the query and the parameters separately to the database adapter, which performs the appropriate operations." Source: [code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17741](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17741)

You need to replace ` with " and put ' around Chicago to make it work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It still doesn't seem to be returning anything but perhaps it's just the query itself, when running in a sql query I can return my expected results, I think I will try to install the Django debug toolbar

Comment: Here is the SQL query it seems to be running ```SELECT `previous_losses_nbav1_with_date_agg`.`ACTUAL OVER UNDER RESULT:` FROM `previous_losses_nbav1_with_date_agg` WHERE (`previous_losses_nbav1_with_date_agg`.`AWAY TEAM:` = Chicago OR `previous_losses_nbav1_with_date_agg`.`HOME TEAM:` = Chicago)```

Comment: @Josh  The SQL query returned as expected. You should check the query by running it in parts.

Comment: I will try to break it up, I would have suspected the query to be ```SELECT `ACTUAL OVER UNDER RESULT:` FROM `previous_losses_nbav2_with_date_agg` WHERE `HOME TEAM:` = 'Chicago' OR `AWAY TEAM:`= 'Chicago'``` as I don't see why I would want my table name randomly dropped in place before each filter

Comment: That is not randomly dropped in, it is used to distinguish between columns of two tables with the same name, especially when using a JOIN in SQL.

Comment: I may not be using some of these query items correctly then. This query is all for a single table, I want to search both columns for that specific keyword and return column X, I am not searching two different tables. My last comment should reference table nbaV1 not v2, it is all one table

Comment: @Josh Yes, you should verify data from the admin panel if it is satisfying the condition you wrote in the query. The query returned is always with the table name before the columns regardless of join used in query, as it is generated automatically to avoid conflicts. Also, consider upvoting and accepting if my answer helped you fix the issue.

Comment: I will def accept it once I get it to work, it's not returning anything, if I go to my admin panel for my table and run the query I posted above in the comments I get my results, when I post what you posted I return nothing, still trying to work it out what I'm missing. What I also am trying to still understand are the () around the conditions of the statement

Comment: can you paste the code of your Django model you are using in the query?

Comment: Yes added to the original question. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for all your help!